# Trying to regain access to a wordpress based website

Tags: php

My Dad has a website based on wordpress, he went into the wordpress dashboard and modified the home page incorrectly appending an extra level to it, then when he exited it made changes resulting in website being messed up and more importantly the login to wordpress has disappeared not allowing him to change it back.

I manually fixed the url to display the wordpress dashboard login, yet even when login it doesnt work, it takes be back to the wrong page.

I don't currently have access to the wordpress database but I do have access to the files generated from the database so my plan was to edit the correct file to set the home page path back to what it should be, hoping that will then allow me to get into Wordpress dashboard. 
But I have very little knowledge of Wordpress, anyone help me here please.

Comment: can you get to the settings by appending this to the url ? wp-admin/options-general.php

Comment: No, this is what Im trying http://painswickgolf.com/blog/wp-admin/options-general.php

Comment: When you say he modified the home page, did he change home.php file or edit something from within the CMS? Did he touch .htaccess or anything in WP settings?

Comment: He did it through the wp dashboard I think he just changed the value of something from painswickgolf.com/blog to painswickgolf.com/blog/?page_id=3

Comment: With the amount of information you are providing all I can say is get access to the database and change the data that you need there.  Maybe in `wp_options`, check the `siteurl` value.  If you need to change the path of specific page check `wp_posts`.

Comment: The information I give is second hand he made it seem like it was obvious what he had changed , I do know it was just one value, I'll look at your suggestions thanks.

Comment: hmm, cant find wp_posts.php or wp_options.php

Comment: If you could delete/rename the `.htaccess` file, you could access the `http://painswickgolf.com/blog/wp-admin/options-general.php` page, because admin page should work without it. Once you logged in, immediately go to the `.../wp-admin/options-permalink.php` page, and fix the permalink settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Changing The Site URL « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) for recovery instructions.

Comment: Seems like this would have been the solution, but unfortunately at his request I used a sledgehammer to crack a nut and dropped the database and reinstalled wordpress so this reply too late for me.

Answer (score 2):

Add `define('RELOCATE',true);` to wp-config.php

Comment: This is a good piece of info to share, but it'd be better if you added some explanation and context, or at least a link to http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method